# type error extend is not a function in styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to use styled-components but get the below error -

```
TypeError: CustomElement.extend is not a function
```

Code:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const CustomElement = styled.div`
  color: green;
  font-size: 30px;
`

const BlueElement = CustomElement.extend`
  color: blue;
`

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CustomElement>
          div
      </CustomElement>
        <BlueElement>
          div
      </BlueElement>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please accept the given answer if it resolves your issue so that it will help future readers

Comment: 77 gold medals ... @user1050619 you have been here long enough to know that you should either accept an answer that helps, or else edit your question (or leave a comment) indicating how it doesn't help.

Answer (score 15):

Change

```
const BlueElement = CustomElement.extend`
  color: blue;
`
```

To

```
const BlueElement = styled(CustomElement)`
   color: blue;
`
```

Comment: This does fix it, but providing a why would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer shows how to fix the problem but doesn't explain *why* the solution fixes it.

The `CustomElement.extend` function was [removed in styled components version 4](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#deprecated-extend), so you must be using version 4 or above, where it no longer exists. It was removed because it was considered a source of confusion for developers (see [this issue on Github](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1546) for more details). As explained, you can use `styled(CustomElement)` to extend your styled components with the newer version instead.